# codenameone android release build shows warning with android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE

Tags: codenameone

I have successfully build the android mobile application and when upload it to the google store. One change I have done from the previous release was adding IOS FaceID fix. I'm not sure if this feature require android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE permission to work on Android devices. I see the following error message.

**New permissions added
"Warning:
Users that have the APK with version code 140 may need to accept the android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE permission, which may result in them not upgrading to this version of the app.
Tip:
Ensure that the new permissions are necessary, and consider mentioning these permissions in the What's new in this release text."**

I don't use any code in the app which require android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE. CN1 includes this build hint on the server when doing the App Store build. code.

Did anyone encounter this issue. Please advise.

Comment: You can check the source code generated by the build to see that this permission isn't added in the manifest nor is it requested in our code. Can you produce a diff between your current version and the previous one to determine exactly what has changed?

Comment: You can include that using the build hint `android.xpermissions=<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" tools:node="remove" />` but I'm not sure if it will have any impact